# Installation VoltDB on MAC

Tags: macos, voltdb

Can anyone help me for installation voltDB on MAC system i am trying to install it using instruction but get error

```
Cannot find config.m4. 
Make sure that you run '/usr/bin/phpize' in the top level source directory of the module
```

I spent a couple of days to solve this issue google it get some post related to this error but not success to solve this issue, because i am new on MAC System so please help to install voltDB with Step by Step i'll very thankful

Answer (score 1):

Installing VoltDB on a Mac uses the same process as on Linux.

The installation instructions are covered in Using VoltDB: [Ch. 2: Installing VoltDB](https://voltdb.com/docs/UsingVoltDB/ChapGetStarted.php)

If you are installing from the source code on Github, you first need to run a build.  There are instructions to do this in Github on the [project wiki](https://github.com/VoltDB/voltdb/wiki/Building-VoltDB).

However, from the error you are seeing, it looks like you are trying to compile the VoltDB PHP client library.  To do that, I recommend downloading the PHP client library from VoltDB.com, since that includes both the PHP client library and the version of the C++ library that it depends on.  It includes build instructions.  If you're getting the source from github, you should know that the latest version of library is the [native branch](https://github.com/VoltDB/voltdb-client-php/tree/native), not master.